# Wordpress Woocommerce страница оформления заказа

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Здравствуйте.
Данные, которые я ввожу на странице оформления заказа. (адрес, населенный пункт и прочее.), можно ли их как-нибудь скопировать и сохранить в массив (сессию)?
Я так понимаю эти данные хранятся в `$woocommerce->customer`.
  Первый адрес пользователя.

```
global $woocommerce;
$abc = $woocommerce->customer->address_1;
```

Как то надо брать переменные после нажатия на кнопку Подтверждение заказа.
Или это не те данные?

```
function my_status_pending($order_id){
            global $woocommerce;
            global $wpdb;
            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
            $my_billing = $order->data['billing'];
            $my_shipping = $order->data['shipping'];
            $contry = $order->data['billing']['country']; // и т.д.
            $days = "123123";

            $OrderData = array(
                'country_code'        => $order->data['billing']['billing_city'],
                'state_code'          => $order->data['billing']['billing_address_1'],
                'city_code'       => $order->data['billing']['country'],
                'status'   => $order->data['billing']['billing_first_name'],
            );
            // Обновляем существующую запись


                $wpdb->insert( 'wp_city_sdek', $OrderData);



        }
```

Comment: а зачем вы мой ответ переписали в вопрос, да еще и с ошибкой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Брать эти данные надо из объекта WC_Order, из массивов billing и shipping. После нажатия на кнопку "Подтвердить заказ" срабатывает хук `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`. Вот рабочий пример:

```
function my_status_pending($order_id){
    global $woocommerce;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $my_billing = $order->data['billing']; // любая переменная
    $my_shipping = $order->data['shipping'];  // любая переменная
    $contry = $order->data['billing']['country']; // и т.д.
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'my_status_pending' );
```

Comment: Сделал аналог вашей функции В таблицу ничего не записалось. В таблице везде поля текст.

Comment: В какую таблицу? В вопросе ни слова ни о каких таблицах. Я вам дал код, который позволяет получить в ваши переменные $my_billing, $my_shipping массивы данных. Вы эти переменные можете использовать как хотите, хоть в таблицы писать, хоть в сессии.